# access a function in another function python

Tags: python, function

When I run this I get a NameError for 'is_number'. Is it possible to access a function in another function? How could I get 'is_number' to work?

```
class Bank_Account():
    account = 0
    def is_number(s):
        try:
            float(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.amt = amt
        if is_number(str(amt)):
            return "Invalid Input"
        else:

            self.account += float(amt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `is_number` in the body of the class, making it a method.

You'll either need to move it *out* of the class body, or make it a proper method by giving it a `self` parameter, and then calling it on the instance with:

```
if self.is_number(amt):
```

Since your `is_number` function has little to do with the rest of the class, you can move it out:

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

class Bank_Account():
    account = 0

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.amt = amt
        if is_number(amt):
            return "Invalid Input"
        else:
            self.account += float(amt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to access a function in another function.

The reason your code isn't working is that `is_number` is defined as a *member* function, or *method*, of the class `Bank_Account`.

This means that it needs to have a `self` parameter in the definition, and you need to call it as `self.is_number`.

Or, alternatively, you need to move it outside the class, so it's a global function.

(Or, even more alternatively, use `@staticmethod`.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Which is why the answer says "That means that it needs to have a `self` parameter in the definition… Or, alternatively, you need to move it outside the class… Or… use `@staticmethod`."

Comment: sorry, indeed, you are mentioning that.

Answer (score -1):

You define the function `is_number` within the class, so you need to call `self.is_number`.

```
class Bank_Account(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.placeholder = None

    account = 0
    def is_number(s):
        try:
            float(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.amt = amt
        if self.is_number(str(amt)):
            return "Invalid Input"
        else:

            self.account += float(amt)
```

Comment: Why the leading underscore in `self._is_number`? And `is_number()` has no `self` parameter, so that'll not work, as it stands.

Comment: This will *not* work; `is_number()` has no `self` parameter, so you get `TypeError: is_number() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`.

Comment: Bank_Account should have a self parameter.

Comment: Your code is getting worse; `__init__` has no body, so that's a `IndentationError` waiting to happen. `Bank_Account` is a *class*, it takes only base classes, not parameters.

Comment: Sorry, used to having other variables in the `__init__` that then get defined in the body. What I meant was that if you create a Bank_Account object you should have a way to reference internally, which is typically to call it self.